# Chrome html5 video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

Problem with playing video on Chrome. Programs work fine on Firefox, Opera and Safari and once (I think) worked fine on Chrome. The past discussions do not help me. Here is a link:
http://faculty.purchase.edu/jeanine.meyer/html5/chooselocation.html
The html5 markup is similar for the 3 videos, but the 1st and 2nd do not work and the 3rd one does!

This script: http://faculty.purchase.edu/jeanine.meyer/html5/collagebase.html
contains code for checking that the videos are loaded but does not play them.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the source ordering for your different formats.

For example, you're currently rendering the following for one of your videos:

```
<video id="fire" loop="loop" preload="auto" controls="controls" style="display: block;">
    <source src="sfire3.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'">
    <source src="sfire3.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs='theora, vorbis'">
    <source src="sfire3.webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm; codec='vp8, vorbis'">
    Your browser does not accept the video tag.
</video>
```

Swap the placement of the first and last `<source>` elements:

```
<video id="fire" loop="loop" preload="auto" controls="controls" style="display: block;">
    <source src="sfire3.webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm; codec='vp8, vorbis'">
    <source src="sfire3.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs='theora, vorbis'">
    <source src="sfire3.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'">
    Your browser does not accept the video tag.
</video>
```